# PHP Codeigniter How to set up Rest Server And Client

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, rest-client, codeigniter-restserver

How to set up rest server and client.
 I read the tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814.
I got idea about restfull services , and rest server work fine , but rest client not.

My problem is I dont get the idea about rest client spark , And the given link CodeIgniter Curl library: http://getsparks.org/packages/curl/show was down , So cant get this.
How do I get this ?

Answer (score 0):

The client mentioned in the post is merely for testing purposes. It is not part of the REST server.

What you need to set up in your code is the REST server library, method of authentication, database tables (if using any), and the controllers that will map your endpoints.

The client concept represents any device/application that will be consuming from or sending data to your REST service through the HTTP methods.

You could be using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) for your testing. It is free and open-source, and very intuitive to use.